# How does Raft guarantee log consistency?

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, distributed-system, raft

I'm learning Raft, and I already know the basic mechanism of Raft.

When a Leader is elected, it is responsible to update the Followers' log to the Leader's one. When updating a Follower, it finds the first matched `<entry, term>` backwards, and update the Follower with the following logs.

How does Raft guarantee the logs of the Leader and the Follower before the matched `<entry, term>` are the same? Will this case happen:

```
                |
Leader          v  
Entry   : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Term    : 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 

Follower
Entry   : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Term    : 1 1 1 1 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 3):

This property of the Raft algorithm is called Log Matching.

> If two logs contain an entry with the same index and term, then the
>   logs are identical in all entries up through the given index

This holds because:

> When sending an AppendEntries RPC, the leader includes the index and
>   term of the entry in its log that immediately precedes the new
>   entries. If the follower does not find an entry in its log with the
>   same index and term, then it refuses the new entries. The consistency
>   check acts as an induction step: the initial empty state of the logs
>   satisfies the Log Matching Property, and the consistency check
>   preserves the Log Matching Property whenever logs are extended. As a
>   result, whenever AppendEntries returns successfully, the leader knows
>   that the follower’s log is identical to its own log up through the new
>   entries.

Source https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf

Comment: Now I understand. Before or after each AppendEntries operation, Raft ensures that every two participants in this protocol satisfies the Log Matching Property.